# Not getting proper date time format in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, controller

I'm unable get local time . im getting data like this from the api

sample data

```
 2017-03-06T09:34:20.545Z
```

Desired Out put

```
3/6/2017, 3:04:20 PM
```

im getting value like this - `06/03/2017 04:34:20 AM`

how to get the proper time in the format "3/6/2017, 3:04:20 PM".

i tried to localize the time but its giving incorrect date time.

data type

```
  public string UpdatedTime { get; set; }
```

string updtime = bin.timestamp;//03/06/2017 12:51:33
            binModel.UpdatedTime = Convert.ToDateTime(updtime).ToString("M/d/yyyy, h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);//expected time - 3/6/2017, 6:21:33 PM

Comment: Why are you trying to store a `DateTime` in a `string` property in the first place? Keep it as the correct type and you don't need to worry about converting any more. Also, how are you creating this "output" that is incorrect?

Comment: Do not *double* `d`, `M`, `H`: let system *skip* zeores: `ToString("d/M/yyyy h:mm:ss tt..` you probably want `h`, not `H` since `21:00 PM` instead of `9:00 PM` looks a bit strange

Comment: Try with Convert.ToDateTime(bin.timestamp).ToString("M/d/yyyy, HH:mm:ss tt"). This will give you desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy,hh:mm:ss tt"); // case sensitive
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have incorrect format here:

```
"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt"
```

`HH` is used for 24 hours format, but you use  `AM/PM` so you need 12 hours format. Use `hh`.

You sample data is:

```
2017-03-06T09:34:20.545Z
```

it means. year is `2017`, month is `03`, day is `06` and the same for time.

For desired output you need `Month/Day/Year`. But you use this format:

```
"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt"
```

here you get `Day/Month/Year`.

You should change your format to (also without zeros in front and with comma):

```
"M/d/yyyy, h:mm:ss tt"
```

Comment: Thanks its working fine...giving desired date time format

Comment: can u tell me how to change to dd/mm/yyyy format, i want to show date first next month then year.

Comment: @Swapna, `d/M/yyyy` - without zeros in fornt or `dd/MM/yyyy` with zeros

Comment: in the localhost im getting correct data but in the remote server , where the application is hosted , there im getting incorrect datetime

Comment: @Swapna, try to delete `ToLocalTime()` call or set appropriate culture instead of Invariant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137367/discussion-between-swapna-and-roma-doskoch).

Answer (score 1):

I personally always [reference this page](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) when I forget how to format timestamps. If you must use strings, and not DateTime, you can do this.

```
obj.UpdatedTime = string.Format("{0: d/m/yyyy, HH:mm:ss tt", Convert.ToDateTime(data)});
```

The format of the string can be whatever your choosing, but the page linked has always been the most helpful for me. If you can use a DateTime property, just do this. You will always want to wrap this in a try/catch and verify you're getting a value you want.

```
obj.UpdatedTime = Convert.ToDateTime(data);
```

Cheers