# unble to get proper order by decending datetime in c#

Tags: c#

i have done datetime order by descending but its showing incorrect descending order. it should come 3/17/2017,3/7/2017,3/6/2017. but im getting below output

sample data

```
130 3/7/2017 1:03:48 PM UP
288 3/6/2017 1:02:59 PM UP
289 3/5/2017 9:57:37 PM DN
343 3/5/2017 1:18:25 PM UP
344 3/4/2017 9:50:12 AM DN
497 3/4/2017 3:03:38 PM
887 3/3/2017 1:17:53 PM DN
888 3/3/2017 1:17:44 PM UP
889 3/17/2017 11:32:48 AM   UP
890 3/17/2017 11:32:38 AM   UP
```

code

```
  public ActionResult pir()
        {
            List<PIRDetailsViewModel> model = new List<PIRDetailsViewModel>();
            model.AddRange(getPirDetails("0000acfffe588041"));

            model = model.OrderByDescending(x => x.UpdatedTime).ToList();
            return View(model);

        }



binModel.UpdatedTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Convert.ToDateTime(bin.timestamp), TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time")).ToString();
```

datatype

```
 public string UpdatedTime { get; set; }
```

Comment: is UpdatedTime is of type Date?

Comment: it is of string datetime. i should have changed to datetime but i kept as string only.

Comment: You convert date to string. So it's sorting alphabetically.

Comment: Always store your data as the best fit type. String is not the best fit for dates.

Comment: [Especially when you have been told previously that this is a terrible idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623065/not-getting-proper-date-time-format-in-c-sharp#comment72374378_42623065)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your UpdatedTime is of type String, Parse it to DateTime or save it as a Date,

```
var orderedList = model.OrderByDescending(x => DateTime.Parse(x.UpdatedTime)).ToList();
```

Comment: Which will break anywhere that doesn't understand US date formats, precisely why data should be stored as the proper type in the first place.